# Lucene.NET Italian Analyzer: Loading Stopwords from file system

Tags: vb.net, lucene.net, analyzer, stop-words

I am using Lucene.NET 3.0.3 on a vb.net 3.5 framework application. I need to pass an Italian stopword file.

Either using a FileInfo or a TextReader, I get always the English stop words, once I have instatiated my analyzer in a standard way:

```
            stopword = New System.IO.FileInfo(stopWordsLocation)
            analyzer = New StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, stopword)
            analyzer = New StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, stopword)
            'here i have still the English stop words if I go through quick-watch my analyzer
```

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: what field are you inspecting with the quickwatch?

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading the static field `STOP_WORDS_SET`? That's the list of english stopwords used if you call the StandardAnalyzer constructor which does not take a stop word list. Your code does not use that constructor, so it should not cause any issues.